# Split new tmux window

Tags: tmux

I am  trying to create a new window in a tmux-session and split it (and afterwards I hope that it'll be possible to execute some commands in the splitted window). Therefore, I'd like to use `new-window`, which should, according to the manpage, support something like `new-window 'vi /etc/passwd'`. Executing `tmux new-window` in an existing session works fine.

Unfortunately, when I open tmux, and run `tmux new-window 'tmux split-window'` or even `tmux new-window 'echo test'`, the command is not executed at all. Other parameters, like `tmux new-window -c "~"` work like expected. A little workaround, nameley using `tmux new-window -t 4 && tmux split-window -t 4` does work, but requires an index.

Why is it not possible to split a pane or just give it an command to execute?

Answer (score 1):

Try, from the command-line:

```
tmux new-window \; split-window
```

The reason that your command `tmux new-window 'echo test'` didn't work as you expected is that by default tmux closes the window upon completion of the `shell-command`. To see for yourself, try instead `tmux new-window top`. There does exist a tmux option `remain-on-exit` that supposedly can be set on a per-session or per-window basis, but I haven't had success using it. Refer to the man page for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `tmux` shortcuts. Start with the `tmux` prefix, usually `Ctrl + b` then:

`%` for vertical split

`"` for horizontal split.

To swap panes use `o` or the arrows.